# Socket.io v1.0.X unknown transport "polling"

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Y have a problem in connection versión 1.0 that I dont had in the versión 0.9.X.

I have Django running in http://app.myhost.com and my node server in http://live.myhost.com:8001

Before I could connect me to the node server like:

Client:

```
io.connect(//live.myhost.com:8001);
```

server:

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']);
```

but now I have a problem (not taking the live url correctly):

```
GET http://app.myhost.com:8000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401468282894-1 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

if I rewrite (io.connect(http://live.myhost.com:8001)) now have a new problem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://live.myhost.com:8001/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401468608168-1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app.myhost.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

in debug mode to socket.io I have more info:

```
engine:core intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +0ms
engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401470024479-48" +0ms
engine unknown transport "polling" +3ms
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? A far as I can see, there are some changes in the 1.0 version of socket.io and the transport jsonp.polling is not supported now. Just type polling, but there are still other problems. My page for now will not work with the new version, too.

Answer (score 11):

In default `Socket.IO 1.0.4` allows `polling` and `websocket` transports. You removed `polling` transport by setting custom transports. Just return the `polling` transport back:

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 
                      'flashsocket', 
                      'htmlfile', 
                      'xhr-polling', 
                      'jsonp-polling', 
                      'polling']);
```

**Updated Apr 3, 2015**

`0.9.15` is last version with valid `set` method. Version `1.0.0-pre` removes `set` method and introduces settings via server initialization. Version `1.0.0-pre2` adds original `set` method for backward compatibility. Use new notation:

```
var socket = io({
  transports: [
    'websocket', 
    'flashsocket', 
    'htmlfile', 
    'xhr-polling', 
    'jsonp-polling', 
    'polling'
  ]
});
```

Comment: As of Socket1 .set is deprecated so you should revise your answer.

Comment: For socket.io 1.0.+ it would be `io.use( ... )`